# Dotnet compliation error; aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompliation.rsp exited with code 1

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following issue in my API where the code is running ok when i try to run it in local host, however when i try to publish it, this error comes up
Help!!

> Error The command ""dotnet" exec --runtimeconfig "~\xxxx-api\API.xxxx\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\API.xxxx.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "~\xxxx-api\API.xxxx\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\API.xxxx.deps.json" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.dll" @"obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"" exited with code 1. API.xxxx        0

- names are crossed out due to company policy :(

Comment: The accepted answer is not a solution to the problem

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone has the same problem:

Add this line o code on csproj:

```
<ProperyGroup>
   ...
   <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish> 
</ProperyGroup>
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6659

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7393

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your comment just lead me to the right way. I checked my latest changes in views which were breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I installed this package under "Get Tools and Features" > "Individual Components" tab, "Cloud, Database, and Server" (heading) > "Web Deploy" Checkbox Option:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what this has to do with this error. Why do you believe this option installs this package? Why would including Web Deploy solve this exception? Can you provide more details on your thinking, and why you believe this is a solution?

Answer (score -3):

Remove the following file:

privateregistry.user.bin

Located in

```
C:\Users\[UserId]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_[UniqueCode]
```

No need to restart computer, now Visual Studio 2017 starts successfully.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31263/vs2017-fails-to-start-with-unknown-error.html

Comment: It has no relation with the question posted